# Fastest way of numerically creating a list of dot products

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, numerics

I have a list of numerical complex 2x2 matrices

```
list = {M[4,3],T[3],M[3,2],T[2],M[2,1],T[1]}
```

(in reality this list contains over 1000 matrices and I have to do many runs, that's why fast would be good. I hope the structure is clear)

I would like to create a list of 2 dimensional vectors structured as follows:

```
vectorlist = {{1,B0}, M[2,1].T[1].{1,B0}, M[3,2].T[2].M[2,1].T[1].{1,B0}, M[4,3].T[3].M[3,2].T[2].M[2,1].T[1].{1,B0}}
```

Note that I do not need this structure, just the result of this multiplications. And since the j vector is `M[j,j-1].T[j-1]` dot the j-1 vector, it should be possible to exploit this to save time rather than calculating each vector on its own. But I am not sure how to do that.

Any additional ideas how to do this faster are very appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First a `CompiledFunction`; it expects the `T`-matrices and the `M` matrices is separate lists.

```
cf = Compile[{{T, _Complex, 3}, {M, _Complex, 3}, {B0, _Complex}},
   Block[{u, n},
    n = Min[Length[T], Length[M]];
    u = {1. + 0. I, B0};
    Join[
     {u},
     Table[
      u = Compile`GetElement[M, i].(Compile`GetElement[T, i].u),
      {i, 1, n}]
     ]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Now you can do quite many such operations per second:

```
n = 1000000;
T = 0.5 RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {n, 2, 2}];
M = 0.5 RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {n, 2, 2}];
cf[T, M, 2.]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.236832

Actually, I made the experience that `Dot` in compiled code for small matrices/vectors tends to be a bit slow. Here is a handwritten expansion of `Dot`, that crucially depends on the undocumented `` Compile`GetElement ``.

```
cg = Compile[{{T, _Complex, 3}, {M, _Complex, 3}, {B0, _Complex}},
   Block[{a, b, n, A, an, bn},
    n = Min[Length[T], Length[M]];
    a = 1. + 0. I;
    b = B0;
    A = Table[0. + 0. I, {n + 1}, {2}];
    A[[1, 1]] = a;
    A[[1, 2]] = b;
    Do[
     an = Compile`GetElement[T, i, 1, 1] a + Compile`GetElement[T, i, 1, 2] b;
     bn = Compile`GetElement[T, i, 2, 1] a + Compile`GetElement[T, i, 2, 2] b;
     a = Compile`GetElement[M, i, 1, 1] an + Compile`GetElement[M, i, 1, 2] bn;
     b = Compile`GetElement[M, i, 2, 1] an + Compile`GetElement[M, i, 2, 2] bn;
     A[[i + 1, 1]] = a;
     A[[i + 1, 2]] = b;
     , {i, 1, n}];
    A
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

This is almost five times as fast on my machine:

```
A1 = cf[T, M, 2.]; // RepeatedTiming // First
A2 = cg[T, M, 2.]; // RepeatedTiming // First
A1 == A2
```

> 0.24
>
> 0.050
>
> True

Beware that calling `cg` with `T` and `M` being lists of matrices of *smaller* size than $2 \times 2$ will cause *Mathematica*'s kernel to crash without warning (because `` Compile`GetElement[M, i, 2, 2] `` is a forbidden memeory access which the OS will prevent by killing the *Mathematica* kernel). At least that is what seems to happen on macos.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I get two error messages: "CreateLibrary::nocomp: A C compiler cannot be found on your system. Please consult the documentation to learn how to set up suitable compilers." and "Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function."    From the Documentation I learn that I need to install a C Compiler on my computer, right? Do you have a recommendation for a free C Compiler?

Comment: On Linux: gcc. On macos: Just install XCode. On Windows: I have heard that Visual Studio were the compiler of choice. But I am not sure. If you do not care that much for speed, just change `CompilationTarget -> "C"` to `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` (Wolfram Virtual Machine). That helps already a lot, but is not as fast as `"C"`.

Comment: thanks a lot! Just a side note: In your code the order of the T and M matrices are reversed with respect to the order of my initial list, right? That's not a problem at all, just to avoid confusion :)

Comment: Hm. I did not really care about it. But the order of the list `T` should be the same as yours: The first `T` is multiplied first. Same with `M`. It is in the nature of successive multiplication from the left, that the last matrix appears as first in the product when seen from the left...